# How to give histogram more variation when values are similar in R?

Tags: r

I have a project that requires selected variables (2) in the data set
to make a histogram of it. The problem is that the data set
that I choose is made with two variables (0,1) so when I create the histogram it does not have any meaning.

```
hist  (relativni.frekfenci, main='Relativni frekfenci prestaveni vo histogram' , xlab='Relativni Frekfenci',ylab='bo ')
```

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you made a bar graph for a dichotomous variable, not a histogram which is for a continuous variable.

Comment: @BillO'Brien any suggestions how can I fix it?

Comment: If you want a histogram you'd need a continuous variable, something like age in years, weight in kg, lengh in mm. If all the values of your variable are 0/1, then a bar graph showing that, say, 70% of rows are coded as 0 and 30% as 1 would be an honest representation of the distribution of your variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try tinkering with `breaks` until you get something that works. Without seeing your data, I cannot do this for you.

#### Example

But here's an example of the same data with `breaks = 3`

```
hist(sqrt(islands), breaks = 3, col = "lightblue", border = "pink")
```

[image]

and again with `breaks = 10`

```
hist(sqrt(islands), breaks = 10, col = "lightblue", border = "pink")
```

[image]